# Fonts and Font Awesome icons not loading over SSL

Tags: css, ssl, https

I'm trying to get my website to load correctly over SSL, and every time I view the page, the icons and font aren't loading.

Here's what I'm using for my CSS and font awesome.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

[Here's a link to the website in case you want to check the full code](https://damadrigames.me)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try remove http: from `href`:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

There is a great article about protocol-relative here: [paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)

Comment: Wasn't enough for me, I had [link](Using nginx): to hide both Cache-control and Pragma: no-cache

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Still not sure what caused it to break in the first place. It was working yesterday, and this morning I had to implement this solution. Nothing changed that I am aware of otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same SSL/TLS error/issue over the chrome. It worked OK on the firefox. I had to switch the sources.

There is issue with MaxCDN you need to use KeyCDN.

Switch from:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

to:

```
<link href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

and maybe its a simple issue of using "http" instead "https" because the google apis use https for secure link transfer. Replace http with https

Answer (score 0):

In my case change `http` source to `https` while using `@import` statement in [*css file*](https://github.com/chetabahana/chetabahana.github.io/blob/master/css/portfolio/layout.css) works fine.

```
@import url(https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css);
[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {font-family: 'fontawesome', sans-serif;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the font-awesome zip (css & assets) and serve them from your own server/directory - instead of using the CDN links.

Then just refer to the font-awesome css file in your own directory using https://

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your webbrowser blocked the HTTP resources from being loaded from a Server that is configured for HTTPS, which is referred to as "Mixed Content", and is flagged as a security risk.

A secure site should never load resources via a non-secure mechanism.

Perhaps your webbrowser auto-updated to a newer version that does not allow Mixed Content to the loaded.

[What is Mixed Content? - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem - after lots of attempts using the CDN links, with and without `https://..`, I decided to download the font-awesome zip file and serve them instead from my own server.

Put all the `css` and `assets` on your own server, instead of loading them from the CDN link with `https://..`

Then, just refer to `font-awesome.css` file using https://..

Eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yourdomain-name.com/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

This fixed it for me, after going round in circles.

Comment: Eg was removed: https://yourdomain-name.com/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css