# Font-Awesome not showing from Facebook or Instagram Apps on Android

Tags: android, html, css, font-awesome

I have a website with the great Font-Awesome icons: http://www.lefrasi.it/.
If you see it from mobile, everything is ok, icons are displayed on every kind of devices.

But if I see my website on Samsung S6 and Galaxy Tab E **from Facebook App** (or Instagram App), icons are not displayed. On iPhone 6 they are visible. So **it seems the problem is only on Android devices**.

Try on Android mobile using Facebook app from https://www.facebook.com/lefrasiit-frasi-belle-aforismi-e-citazioni-1020903941368734/ and then click on my website link (for example).
It seems that FB or Instagram use iframe to show my website, and icons are "invisible", but if you click on them (for example on the main nav menu on the right there is a search icon), they work. So it seems icons are there, but are invisible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I find a possible solution. 
The problem seems to be including external css of font-awesome from maxcdn.

I used: https//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

**Including and loading it from my theme folder**, seems to fix the problem.

I tried also to load externally using "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" (without "https") and it works too.

So the problem could be loading external font-awesome css using https protocol.

Answer (score 0):

```
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

is the correct solution.
Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26616469/4769949