# Grails app, FontAwesome icons become invisible with https

Tags: grails, https, font-awesome

I inherited this Grails (v3.3.0) app and need to add SSL to the game. The app is already serving properly within the intranet using http (ie: no www links). It uses FontAwesome v4.7 which displays FA icons fine in http. However, after I've added SSL to the equation, the FA icons are not displayed anymore.

Upon closer examination the problem seems to be related to:

`[https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver IO Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /XXX/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. Stacktraace follows:...`

But the thing is I can hit up this URL to get/download the file:
https://localhost:8443/XXX/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eof

So it looks like tomcat is serving properly and I am not sure what the problem is. Can any guru share your insight?

[Directories look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vb0c.png)

This is the snippet of **application.groovy**

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
   [pattern: '/',                 access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/index',            access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/index.gsp',        access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/Absolute/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/font-awesome/**',  access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/js/**',            access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/css/**',           access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/images/**',        access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/fonts/**',         access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico',   access: ['permitAll']]
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
   [pattern: '/assets/**',        filters: 'none'],
   [pattern: '/**/js/**',         filters: 'none'],
   [pattern: '/**/css/**',        filters: 'none'],
   [pattern: '/**/images/**',     filters: 'none'],
   [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico',   filters: 'none'],
   [pattern: '/**',               filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS']
]
```

This is the snippet in my **application.yml**

```
server:
   contextPath: /XXX
---
environments:
   production:
      server:
         port: 8443
         ssl:
            enabled: true
            key-alias: tomcat
            key-store: c:/ssl/keystore.jks
            key-store-password: password
            key-store-type: JKS
---
```

The snippet of code to include FA in *.gsp:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${request.contextPath}/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

Inside the font-awesome.css, there is this at the top:

```
@font-face {
  :
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  :
}
```

This is the snippet of code to display FA icon:

```
<div class="section">
   <label for="username" class="field prepend-icon">
      <input type='text' name='username' class='gui-input'>
      <label for='username' class='field-icon'>
         <i class='fa fa-user'></i>
      </label>
   </label>
```

PS: I cannot access external links so I can only href to intranet

Comment: I don't think you can mix http/https within the same page, maybe this is of help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616400/fonts-and-font-awesome-icons-not-loading-over-ssl

Comment: MikeW, I don't want to mix http and https. Do you mean by doing '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot', it will be http?

Comment: You've switched to https but some of your resources are being fetched over http

Comment: The only reference to those awesome font files is in font-awesome.css, so I am not sure where else is trying to load those file over http. I have also tried changing font-awesome.css to use full path (ie:  https://localhost:8443/XXX/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eof) but Grails is still throwing the exception.